# Angular2 routing - adding the hashtag using LocationStrategy not working?

Tags: url, angular, hashtag, angular2-routing

I'm following the simple quickstart app from the Angular2 docs and I'm using a spring backend to run it. My problem is that the angular router ditched the hashtag from the URL so what should have been `example.com/#/dashboard` is now `example.com/dashboard`.

I am using the `LocationStrategy` method specified in a bunch of posts on StackOverflow. Below is my simple example:

`File: main.ts`

```
///<reference path="../node_modules/angular2/typings/browser.d.ts"/>

import {bootstrap} from 'angular2/platform/browser'
import {provide} from 'angular2/core';
import {LocationStrategy, HashLocationStrategy} from 'angular2/router';

import {TestComponent} from './simple/test.component'

bootstrap(
    TestComponent, 
    [
        provide(LocationStrategy, { useClass: HashLocationStrategy })
    ]
);
```

`File: test.component.ts`

```
import {Component} from 'angular2/core';
import {RouteConfig, ROUTER_DIRECTIVES, ROUTER_PROVIDERS } from 'angular2/router';

@Component({
    selector: 'test1',
    template: "<h1>This is test1 component</h1>"
})
export class Test1 { };

@Component({
    selector: 'test2',
    template: "<h1>This is test2 component</h1>"
})
export class Test2 { };

@Component({
    selector: 'my-app',

    template: `
        <h1>This is my test app</h1>
        <nav>
            <a [routerLink]="['Test1']">Test1</a>
            <a [routerLink]="['Test2']">Test2</a>
        </nav>
        <router-outlet></router-outlet>
    `,

    directives: [ROUTER_DIRECTIVES],

    providers: [ROUTER_PROVIDERS]
})
@RouteConfig([
    {
        path: '/test1',
        name: 'Test1',
        component: Test1
    },
    {
        path: '/test2',
        name: 'Test2',
        component: Test2
    }
])
export class TestComponent { }
```

`File: index.html`

```
<html>
    <head>

        <base href="/">

        <title>This is an Angular 2 test</title>

        <!-- Angular dependencies -->
        <script src="/node_modules/es6-shim/es6-shim.js"></script>
        <script src="/node_modules/systemjs/dist/system-polyfills.js"></script>
        <script src="/node_modules/angular2/bundles/angular2-polyfills.js"></script>
        <script src="/node_modules/systemjs/dist/system.src.js"></script>
        <script src="/node_modules/rxjs/bundles/Rx.js"></script>
        <script src="/node_modules/angular2/bundles/angular2.dev.js"></script>
        <script src="/node_modules/angular2/bundles/router.dev.js"></script>

        <!-- App -->
        <script>

            System.config({
                packages: {
                    app: {
                        format: 'register',
                        defaultExtension: 'js'
                    }/*,
                    'node_modules': {
                        format: 'cjs',
                        defaultExtension: 'js'
                    }*/
                }
            });

            System.import('app/main').then(null, console.error.bind(console));

        </script>

    </head>
    <body>
        <my-app></my-app>
    </body>
</html>
```

I'm using `Angular2 2.0.0-beta.9` and this is the behavior that I see. Note that none of the 2 paths in the @RouteConfig are marked with `useAsDefault: true`.

When I try to open up `http://localhost:8080/#/test1` the page opens fine, but when I click on one of the 2 anchors in the TestComponent template, the hashtag gets dropped.

Then if I set `path1` to be `useAsDefault: true`, the hashtag gets dropped immediately even when I try to visit `http://localhost:8080/#/test1`.

Can someone please tell me if I'm doing something wrong or if that's a bug? I just want to get the hashtag back in the URL.

Comment: What does your route configuration look like? How do you navigate to that route?

Comment: P.S. I did try to manually add the hashtag but that broke the whole app so I guessed I'm not meant to touch there :)

Comment: It works fine with the same implementation in beta-9. Have you done something extra ordinary in your app?If yes, let us know.

Comment: I don't think so - I'm just following the quickstart from [link]https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/quickstart.html[/link] . It does work for me as well but once it loads the page the hashtag is automatically dropped. Does it get preserved in the URL for you?

Comment: Without server side code and navigation (means without server interaction) try to run you app and check if it works ?  It means just with angular2 and route check if every things work as expected.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**Angular2 <= RC.5**

The `ROUTER_PROVIDERS` need to be added before `LocationStrategy` otherwise your previously added `LocationStrategy` gets overridden.

```
bootstrap(
    TestComponent, 
    [
        ROUTER_PROVIDERS, 
        // must be listed after `ROUTER_PROVIDERS`
        provide(LocationStrategy, { useClass: HashLocationStrategy })
    ]
);
```

delete this line

```
providers: [ROUTER_PROVIDERS]
```

from `TestComponent`

Comment: Thanks A TON!!! This was driving me nuts - now that you pointed it out I see what's happening. Tested it and it all works now. Thanks again!

Comment: Glad to hear! This is one of the common pitfalls people run into when starting with Angular DI.

Comment: Thank you for this Great response, i was having trouble with my app because I added router-providers in the components and bootstrap class, since I removed it from components it works!

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer Your answer helped me(stucked up with this for several days)..I do have a small query.. why should we remove `providers: [ROUTER_PROVIDERS]` from `main-app` component? & then for trial, I made bootstrap like `bootstrap(AppComponent, []);` and then added those dependency inside `AppComponent` like `providers: [
        ROUTER_PROVIDERS, ,
        provide(LocationStrategy, { useClass: HashLocationStrategy })
    ]`..do you know reason behind why it doesn't work..

Comment: I haven't found explicit information but I have experienved it myself that the Router only works when `ROUTER_PROVIDERS` are added to `bootstrap()`

Answer (score 0):

With your implementation everything seems perfect. 
Now, Please try to delete ***`browser's cache memory`*** and try. I hope it will start working !!!
I faced this problem when trying for your problem.

Comment: That didn't work - thanks for looking into it tho. I always do hard refresh (ctr + f5), I also tried incognito mode, then cleared the cash and finally I tried other browsers that I hadn't used the webapp in (so no cache there) and still the same thing. When I open up http://localhost:8080/#/dashboard the page loads and it gets immediately changed to http://localhost:8080/dashboard. I'll keep digging until I figure it out and I'll post with the solution once I figure it out. Thanks again.

Comment: Okay No problem. I faced it so put it here as an answer and thought might help you or others... Never mind ! I think something is there which overwrites your configuration or something but hard to tell you without inspecting your code. I hope soon you'll be able to solve it by your own.