# Angular 2: url change in the browser but the view is not displayed

Tags: angular, angular2-routing

I have a simple App I have an issue when I try to navigate to a route.
My main component:

```
    @Component({
    selector: 'my-app',
    template: `
    <ul class="my-app">
        <li>
            <a [routerLink]="['Login']">Login</a>    
        </li>
        <li>
            <a [routerLink]="['Projects']">Projects</a>  
        </li>
    </ul> 
     <br>
    <router-outlet></router-outlet>`,
    directives: [ROUTER_DIRECTIVES],
    providers: [ROUTER_PROVIDERS]
})
@RouteConfig([
    {
        path: '/Login',
        name: 'Login',
        component: LoginFormComponent,
        useAsDefault: false
    },
    {
        path: '/Projects',
        name: 'Projects',
        component: ListProjectsComponent,
        useAsDefault: true
    }
 ])

    export class AppComponent { ...
    ...
```

and I have a basic component

```
@Component({
    selector: 'login-form',
    template: 
      `
        <button (click)="goToProjects()">Go To Projects!</button>
      `,
    directives: [ROUTER_DIRECTIVES],
    providers: [LoginService, ROUTER_PROVIDERS]
})

export class LoginFormComponent implements OnInit {
...
 goToProjects(){
         let link = ['Projects',{}];
         this.router.navigate(link);
    }
..
}
```

I added the base Href to the main page 'index.html'

```
<head>
    <base href="/">
  </head>
```

When I click the button, the url in the address bar change but the view is not displayed, what may go wrong ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I "accidentally" found this [Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35972936/2136116)  for another question

```
bootstrap(
    TestComponent, 
    [
        ROUTER_PROVIDERS, 
        // must be listed after `ROUTER_PROVIDERS`
        provide(LocationStrategy, { useClass: HashLocationStrategy }) // not  interested in this just in the original answer 
    ]
);

providers: [ROUTER_PROVIDERS] // <-- ** delete this line this is what worked!**
from LoginComponent
```

**So, If Bootstrap class already declared "ROUTER_PROVIDERS" then I's required to remove them from every component**, Some operation fails silently: navigation, or hashbang (as in the original answer) and maybe other things ..

Comment: strangely, when i implement this solution, it appears to work, but now all of my pages load very slowly and get increasingly slower.  By the third click in the nav, I'm waiting 5-10 seconds for the view to update.

Comment: this ROUTER_PROVIDERS is depreciated.
any update on the new alternative?
the issue is my url changes but component does't load and i don't have bootstrap either, i have material.
advice ?