# How to set Bootstrap navbar selected to be “active” class in Angular 2 RouterModule?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, angular, angular2-routing, nav

I have a sidenav bar with some tabs

```
<div class="side-wrap-div">
        <div class="list-group sidebar-nav">
            <li class="list-group-item borderBottomMenu active" >
                <a href="#/{{ DocumentURL }}">Document</a>
                <span class="marker-logo"></span>
                <span class="logo document-logo-click" ></span>
            </li>
        </div>
        <div class="list-group bottom-fixed">
            <div  id="collapse3" *ngIf="showContact">
                <a href="#/contact/{{ currentTaskId }}" class="panel-collapse list-group-item collapse">
                    <span class="logo contact-logo" ></span>Contact
                </a>
        </div>
    <div>
```

How to set the navbar selected to be active? I'm using RouterModule(not [routerLink]) and have declared my routing in app.routing.ts.

Comment: Did you try [routerLinkActive]="['active']"

Comment: @Habeeb In my case where do I put that? With <a href.....</a>?

Comment: @Habeeb I tried but the problem is,  it is displaying as highlighted or selected

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35969445/angular2-routing-adding-the-hashtag-using-locationstrategy-not-working
see this

Answer (score 6):

It works for me by using

`<a class="nav-link" routerLink="my-route" routerLinkActive="active">My Route</a>`

`routerLinkActive="active"` will add the "active" class to the `<a>` element.

Found it there: [Router directives](https://angular.io/guide/router#router-directives)

You might have to use defined routes, described here [Define routes](https://angular.io/guide/router#define-routes).