# Nginx not show urls of angular 4

Tags: django, angular, nginx

I am deploy my web server in Django with Angular4 into my LightSail server but I have a problem, because I try access to my page `example.com` and redirect to `example.com/home`, no problem I see my page without problems, but If I try to reload the page it sends me a message as if the route did not exist, being that in my local if I can do it without problem.

this is my config in `vim /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/trackerServer`,
I will be honest, I followed a guide since I do not handle much with `nginx` from 
[LightSail with Django](https://gist.github.com/ganmedia/afbada8ff6ff1733e27f7fd818eb34fd)

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name 54.175.253.151;

    location = /favicon.ico { access_log off; log_not_found off; }
    location /static/ {
        root /home/ubuntu/tracker-web/trackerServer;
    }

    location / {
        include proxy_params;
        proxy_pass http://unix:/home/ubuntu/tracker-web/trackerServer/trackerServer.sock;
    }
}
```

I discard that my problem is with gunicorn.

Someone has gone through the same and has managed to solve this problem of routing?

Answer (score 0):

This question has nothing related to django, and it's not an nginx or gunicorn problem.

You need to add LocationStrategy on your providers.

Take a look at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35969445/angular2-routing-adding-the-hashtag-using-locationstrategy-not-working)

Comment: But I am reading others questions, there are people that solution this problem with only nginx, are you sure?

Answer (score 0):

Angular's documentation has a section for [server configuration](https://angular.io/guide/deployment#routed-apps-must-fallback-to-indexhtml). When using the HTML5 style routing you have to redirect all urls to `index.html` in nginx configuration:

> NGinx: use try_files, as described in Front Controller Pattern Web
>   Apps, modified to serve index.html:
>
> ```
> try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html;
> ```

OR

Use the `HashLocationStrategy` as mentioned in another answer.